# how to split number and char in a mixed string

Tags: mysql

I have a one column called `size` and it has values like these: `236ml` `50g` `100g` `6 x 2pk`.
I want to split number of size and unit separately from this field.
like this:

- `236: ml`
- `50: g`
- `100: g`
- `6: 2pk`

I think I should use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Please show the code you are attempting and explain the problem you are having with it - [you have at least tried?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use querys like this:

```
SELECT val+0 as field1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, val+0, -1) as field2
FROM testtable;

SELECT CONCAT(val+0 ,': ' , SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, val+0, -1)) as fields
FROM testtable;
```

** Sample **

```
mysql> select * from testtable;
+----+---------+
| id | val     |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 236ml   |
|  2 | 50g     |
|  3 | 100g    |
|  4 | 6 x 2pk |
+----+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT val+0 as field1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, val+0, -1) as field2
    -> FROM testtable;
+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 |
+--------+--------+
|    236 | ml     |
|     50 | g      |
|    100 | g      |
|      6 |  x 2pk |
+--------+--------+
4 rows in set, 6 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(val+0 ,': ' , SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, val+0, -1)) as fields
    -> FROM testtable;
+-----------+
| fields    |
+-----------+
| 236: ml   |
| 50: g     |
| 100: g    |
| 6:  x 2pk |
+-----------+
4 rows in set, 6 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here a little describtion:

1. if you add a value to a string MySQL first convert this string to a number, but only the digits start from left.
   so SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX will give 256
2. SUBSTRING_INDEX will split a string a a pattern and returns first from left (1) piece or the first from right (-1) piece:

SUBSTRING_INDEX( "256ml" , "256" , -1) gives "ml"

Comment: Thank you. Bernd Buffen.
It works for me. But not sure how it works.
Could you let me explain in brief?

Comment: And there is one more problem. If I run this query, some fields duplicated, and so I had to use GROUP BY to prevent it. Believe you already know how to handle this too.